# Switching from a region to another in Marionette, views are not rendered correctly

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm working with `Marionette` and I have the following problem.

I've created a layout with two different regions. On `initialize` the layout loads two views in two regions of my layout. Say `ViewA` and `ViewB`. Within `ViewA` an event is triggered. The event is consumed by the layout to switch and other two views are injected. Say `ViewC` and `ViewD`.
Whenever the switching is performed, `ViewC` and `ViewD` do not have the same style (also the css) that I applied to them. In particular, jQuery Mobile styles are not applied. Any advice?

Here some code where comments highlight the important parts.

```
onConfirm : function() {        
        this.leftView =  new ViewC();
        this.rightView = new ViewD();

        this.leftRegion.show(this.leftView);                                                                        
        this.rightRegion.show(this.rightView);

        // FIX calling trigger('create') seems fix the problem. Why? Is this correct?
        this.$el.trigger('create');
    },

initialize : function() {
        // listen for event triggered from ViewA
        // e.g. GloabalAggregator.vent.trigger("ga:confirm");
        // where "ga:confirm" is a simple string
        GloabalAggregator.vent.on("ga:confirm" , this.onConfirm, this);  

        this.leftView =  new ViewA(), // creating here a new ViewC the style is applied correctly
        this.rightView = new ViewB(); // creating here a new ViewD the style is applied correctly
    },

onRender : function () {
        this.leftRegion.show(this.leftView);                                                                        
        this.rightRegion.show(this.rightView);
    }
```

**EDIT**

Calling `trigger('create')` seems fix the problem. Why? Is this correct?

Comment: This code looks correct, unless I'm missing something. Can you reproduce your problem in a jsFiddle?

Comment: What exactly the point of showing JS code if the problem is with style? obviously something wrong with css hierarchy. Check your css, with chrome developer console(or any other) check your generated layout. Without seeing both layout and css it's hard to point out the real problem. But it's there

Comment: This code definitely does `not` look correct unless this is a patchwork of multiple views. You are clearly clobbering your region objects by assigning views to the same variable, namely `leftRegion` and `rightRegion`. Not sure this is your problem but it is definitely a problem with the posted code.

Comment: @DavidSulc I'll try to create a self contained jsFiddle. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewHubbs I fixed the typo in my code. Cheers.

Comment: @DavidSulc Now with `trigger('create')`, the problem it is fixed. But why?

Comment: That is a puzzler. Pretty sure that `create` isn't even a Marionette view event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add new html to page (add new rendered view, swap view for some other view, etc..), you have to let jQuery mobile know about this.

"create" event is used to enhance "raw" html with jQuery Mobile widgets. More info can be found here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html
Look for "Enhancing new markup" section.