# Is this pattern correct for performing region switching with Marionette?

Tags: javascript, layout, backbone.js, marionette

This question is based on my previous one [Switching from a region to another in Marionette, views are not rendered correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976750/switching-from-a-region-to-another-in-marionette-views-are-not-rendered-correct). It differs from it since I'm asking if the approach I'm following is correct or it exists another approach to perform the switching between regions.

I've created a layout with two different regions. On `initialize` the layout loads two views in two regions of my layout. Say `ViewA` and `ViewB`. Within `ViewA` an event is triggered. The event is consumed by the layout to switch and other two views are injected. Say `ViewC` and `ViewD`.

Is this approach correct or do I have to follow another pattern? Routing?

Here some code where comments highlight the important parts.

```
onConfirm : function() {        
        this.leftView =  new ViewC();
        this.rightView = new ViewD();

        this.leftRegion.show(this.leftView);                                                                        
        this.rightRegion.show(this.rightView);
    },

initialize : function() {
        // listen for event triggered from ViewA
        // e.g. GloabalAggregator.vent.trigger("ga:confirm");
        // where "ga:confirm" is a simple string
        GloabalAggregator.vent.on("ga:confirm" , this.onConfirm, this);  

        this.leftView =  new ViewA(), // creating here a new ViewC the style is applied correctly
        this.rightView = new ViewB(); // creating here a new ViewD the style is applied correctly
    },

onRender : function () {
        this.leftRegion.show(this.leftView);                                                                        
        this.rightRegion.show(this.rightView);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch between views in a `Layout` usually a [Controller](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.controller.md) is used, have a look at [this gist](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Using-a-controller-to-change-content-in-a-marionette.layout) for an example.

Basically you will have to create a new controller

```
var controller = Marionette.Controller.extend({
  initialize: function(options){
    this.leftRegion = options.leftRegion;
    this.rightRegion = options.rightRegion;
  },

  swap: function() {
    // do the region swapping here
  }
});
```

You could create it like this from the view:

```
var controller = new MyController({
  leftRegion: this.leftRegion,
  rightRegion: this.rightRegion
});
```

(where `this` referes to the view) and have it listen on that event with the help of [listenTo](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#binding-to-view-events).

A couple more examples from the author of Marionette you might find useful:

- [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/M5J8Q/)
- [wiki article](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Using-a-controller-to-change-content-in-a-marionette.layout)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. +1. In the link there is an example for using it (see second snippet). The region that is injected into `options` is the main one. How to pass (or assign) one or more regions that belong to a Layout? Ciao!!

Comment: heheh ciao :), I edited my answer, see if that is what you meant.